# How to remove empty CSS property by PHP?

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

I have a string like this

```
.header{
font-family:;
background-color:red;
color:blue;
line-height:;
}

.footer{
background-color:green;
color:;
}
```

I want to convert this string-like this

```
.header{
background-color:red;
color:blue;
}
.footer{
background-color:green;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: 1. From where are you receiving such input? 2. Empty properties are ignored in CSS, so what is the purpose of this exercise?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm generating internal CSS dynamically. Which shows into the browser like this. https://prnt.sc/ry0lw2

So I want to get rid of the propertied that does not have any value.

I can achieve this adding condition each time I show the dynamic CSS value ( https://prnt.sc/ry0off ). But I'd like to know if there are any other handy ways to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
preg_replace('/.*:\s*;/i', '', $string);
```

although, the output would include `color:blue;` too and not just `background-color:red;` for `.header`?

Comment: Yes, You are right. I'm sorry for the mistake.
The code is working properly. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)